# Run time error 13 Type mismatch error

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I am trying to write a code to import data from MS access database, everytime i run the macro I keep getting this error, I am unable to figure out what wrong with the code. Can you please tell me what the error is:

```
 With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
            "ODBC;DSN=MS Access Database;DBQ=" & db_fullname & ";DefaultDir=" & db_dir & ";DriverId=25;FIL" _
            ), Array("=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;")), Destination:=Range( _
            "$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandText = Array( _
            "SELECT INNW_CFC_1X.Date_Cascade_Sector_Band, INNW_CFC_1X.Cascade_Sector_band, INNW_CFC_1X.Date, INNW_CFC_1X.Market, INNW_CFC_1X.`BSC Name`, INNW_CFC_1X.`Cluster ID`, INNW_CFC_1X.`Cascade ID`, INNW_CFC" _
            , _
            "_1X.`BTS ID`, INNW_CFC_1X.Sector, INNW_CFC_1X.Band, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc18, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc30, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc53, INNW_CFC_1X.`Total RF CFC`, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc84, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc85, INNW_CFC_1X.`Total Capaci" _
            , _
            "ty CFC`, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc26, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc49, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc102, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc2, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc54, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc99, INNW_CFC_1X.`Total BH CFC`, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc31, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc29, INNW_CFC_1X" _
            , _
            ".cfc81, INNW_CFC_1X.`Total Parameter CFC`, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc16, INNW_CFC_1X.cfc17, INNW_CFC_1X.`Total IVHHO CFC`" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `" & db_fullname & "`.INNW_CFC_1X " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "WHERE (INNW_CFC_1X.Date>={ts '" & start_date2 & " 00:00:00'} And INNW_CFC_1X.Date<={ts '" & end_date2 & "" _
            , _
            " 00:00:00'}) " & query_string & "")

    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_MS_Access_Database"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Comment: What line is highlighted when you get the error?

Comment: The whole select statement is highlighted

Answer (score 0):

Access uses square-brackets [ ] in place of the back-ticks that other databases use (MySQL).

**Date** is also a [reserved word](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) in Access and should also be enclosed in square brackets or, much better!, rename this field.

BTW It is hard to read, but it looks like all your data is coming from a single table INNW_CFC_1X, so you don't have to repeat this table-name for all the fields.